# Sort NSArray of NSArray of dictionaries

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, dictionary, nsarray

I have a parentArray with child arrays at it indexes. Each child array has a dictionary with several key-value pairs. One key has a child dictionary as its value. Based on one of the values of this child dictionary I want to sort the parentArray.

```
ParentArray [
    ChildArray [{
        parentKey: {
                childKey: <the value to sort parentArray>
            }
    }],
    ChildArray [{
        parentKey: {
            childKey: <the value to sort parentArray>
        }
    }]
]
```

The value of the childKey is the one I want to sort my ParentArray on.

Comment: OK so what have you tried?

Comment: What I'm doing is converting child array into custom objects and then sort the parent on that custom object's attribute. It will definitely solve the problem but want to know if there is a more direct approach.

Comment: `[NSArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:]` would work.

Comment: Can you elaborate how to pick the childKey?

Comment: Thanks trojanfoe. got it to work.

Comment: Why do you have these child arrays that only have one element each?

Comment: This is the response Im receiving from a web service call. Can't argue with the web devs. :(

Comment: If you got this to work, please consider adding an answer, to benefit future readers - they may run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arrParent = [arrParent sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id arrChild1, id arrChild2) {
    NSDictionary *dict1 = [(NSArray *)arrChild1 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSDictionary *dict2 = [(NSArray *)arrChild2 objectAtIndex:0];
    int user1 = [[dict1 objectForKey:@"id"] intValue];
    int user2 = [[dict2 objectForKey:@"id"] intValue];

    if (user1 > user2)
    {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else if (user1 < user2)
    {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }


    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

got help [here](http://www.devfright.com/nsarray-sortedarrayusingcomparator-tutorial/)